# REQUEST: Walk sign chirps

Tags: sound-effects, city, urban, traffic

Hi everyone!

Does anyone happen to have a recording of the walk sign chirps that I can do a sound trade for?  I could go out and do a rogue recording late at night but I though it would be best to ask here first unless somebody's already done just that :)

I'm not seeking the voice saying "cross sign to walk for **_**", just the digital chirps.  If you happen to have to have the "beep boop" chirp of hitting the walk sign button, that would be a plus.

If anyone would be so kind as to help and willing to trade, I'd love to know.  Thanks!

Comment: What city? Walk signs are different...for example, here in Chicago they don't make any noise.

Comment: Ah, failed to mention that.  Los Angeles is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks everybody for being a help!  I was not expecting such interest in this, although it has been very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://soundcloud.com/chrisnealysound/berkeley-5pm-crossing-chirp-2

http://soundcloud.com/chrisnealysound/berkeley-5pm-crossing-chirp

here are the two tracks from Berkeley of chirps

Comment: Those sound just like the ones in LA.  If you don't mind my asking, how'd you mic these?  I tried a set last night but having the mic right against the speaker didn't quite capture the high ping that yours did - it's like it needed some air or something to propagate more to sound like what you captured

Comment: Well I had sanken cs1e  to mixpre to H4n and I miced them closely but not as close as I could, I kind of rushed through them because I wasn't sure thats the kind you wanted.  I can google maps you the address where I miced them, the refelections may attribute to some of the ping.  I'll record some more next week and see if I can get them more clean.

Shattuck Ave & Center St
Berkeley, CA 94704 google maps it and you can see the street view.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Yeah, these are what I was looking for indeed.  I rolled out at around 2AM with my H4n onboards but even then it was one of those nights were the traffic drone was heavier (some nights it's non-existent which is weird).  Maybe what I did was mic it way too close so it was capturing the ultra-dry synthesized sound that they embedded into the device, rather than giving it some air to develop and create the more natural-sounding sharper ping.

You're more than welcome to to capture cleaner ones if you're up for it :)

Comment: Please give me a shout at steve (at) stavrosound (dot) com if you'd like do a trade or something.

Comment: SO I just got back from recording the sign again, this time brought out the big guns, but that chirp sounded the same no matter how I mic'd it - so it seems that the lights down here where I was use a very crappy recording/beep in the electronics themselves, whereas the light you recorded had a more pure, sharper beep in the electronics.  So what we captured was simi8lar, but slightly different timbres... guess erverything ISN'T made the same eh? ;)

Comment: Thats Berkeley for ya...

Comment: I'll capture some more Wednesday


Answer (score 3):

This is a long shot, but I just created a little programme for you to generate your own. The idea is that you'll have a SUPER clean version of it, and then you can add the plugins you want to make it sound like it's in your desired space.

The problem is I have no idea what LA pedestrian crossing beeps sound like, so I'm basing it off the UK one. You need to add your own resonance (from the sound it would make from being in a box), and maybe add your own harmonic distortion rather than the one I added.

I based this off the code from Andy Farnel's book: [Designing Sound](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=12282)

Here's the link to the [Pedestrian Crossing Generator](http://www.soundplusdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/software/PedestrianCrossing.zip). let me know how it goes :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not running MacOS so it appears it can't run.  Too bad, would have loved to have to checked it out.

Comment: @Stavrosound Oh pity... I'll see if I can find someone on a PC to compile it for me

Answer (score 1):

I have one recording, although not sure how much car noise was in it. It was a quick record on my way to the parking garage here in LA. 96k 24bit.. PM me?  or What's your email?

Comment: I'd love to take a listen and see if it's workable and make a sound trade.  My email is steve (at) stavrosound (dot) com.

Comment: Sorry! I spaced this.. turns out it was just the beeps of me hitting the crosswalk button. Did you get what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

I have one from Nashville...but there's a lot street noise that comes along with it.

Comment: Darn, unfortunately I'm seeking one that's pretty clean (squeaky clean I know is unrealistic to ask).  Thanks for the response though.  I may just have to hike it down to an area of town I know is dead around midnight and kiss my H4n up against the speaker on the bottom of the walk sign.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be on the lookout this friday to get some chirps from Berkeley